# What credential is used inside AWS EKS to access AWS service such as SNS.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

How to configure the credential to use AWS service from inside the EKS. I can not use AWS SDK for this specific purpose. I have mentioned a role with required permission in the yaml file but it does not seem like it is picking up the role.

ThankYou
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'd want to apply some level of logic to allow the pods themselves to obtain IAM credentials from STS.  AWS does not currently (its re:Invent now so you never know) provide a native-way to do this.  The two community solutions we've implemented are:

kube2IAM: https://github.com/jtblin/kube2iam

kIAM: https://github.com/uswitch/kiam

Both work well in production/large environments in my experience. I prefer kIAM's security model, but both get the job done.

Essentially the work the same basic way ... intercepting (for lack of a better word) communications b/t the SDK libraries in the container and STS, matching identity of the pod with an internal role dictionary, and then obtaining STS credentials for that role and handing those creds back to the container.  The SDK isn't inherently aware its in a container, its just doing what it does anywhere ... walking its access tree until it sees the need to obtain creds from STS and receiving those.

Answer (score 0):

According to the AWS official documentation, AWS new feature eliminates the need for third-party solutions such as `kiam` or `kube2iam`.

You can use the following AWS IAM roles for service accounts. Just follow all step by step guideline mentioned in the link below to enable IAM roles for service accounts:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html